# Restore reminders in Google Calendars

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

I accidentally switched back to Google Tasks in Google Calendar. I still have my reminders, I can see them on Android, but the reminder calendar is gone from the web app, and I can't see my reminders there.

How can I add my reminders again to Google Calendar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Google Calendar website, on the left side, click the drop down arrow next to Google Tasks. There should be an option to switch to reminders.

Comment: And what if I don't have Google Tasks on the Google Calendar website either?

Comment: OK, it's just that I had a "Tasks" calendar which was inactive. After that your method worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If reminders are still not showing after you marked its tickbox, try just refreshing the webpage. It worked for me that way.

Answer (score 0):

I erased all the reminders from the "reminder"and the "default" tab's in "Google Task".
I then  re made my "reminders" in the "reminders" home page.
I also changed the colors of the "Reminders" and "Task" on Google calendar.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155067)

Comment: And that worked? Right now, it's not clear if you still have the same problem or posted a workaround ... by the way, welcome to [webapps.se]!